# How to add multiple versions of the same featured image for SEO reasons?

Tags: plugins, media, thumbnails, library

I am currently writing a plugin that optimizes category pages in WooCommerce.  The idea behind it is that a product can appear in multiple category pages and for every category page it appears in, will have a different ALT tag.  The one component I can't figure out yet is how to give each featured image file a different file name based on each category.

So example

1. Widget A is a part of Category A and Xategory x
2. Wigdet A Filenames: `wigeta-categorya.jpg`, `widgeta-categoryx.jpg`

Based on my SEO's research, this is the approach we need to take.  Any idea on how this can be accomplished?

I know that I need to be dynamically generating new thumbnails to accomplish this but how can I **effectively** add this to the media gallery?

Comment: When you upload an image it is copied in some sizes, by default 4, and IIRC Woocommerce add more sizes, so there are, let's say 6 image files for every images. You should multiply 6 x the categories the product belong: this is a disk space hell. After that, if you reach your goal, in your category archives you'll have a lot of image names named like 'something-catname.jpg' where the cat name is repeated a lot of times. To search engines it may appear as an over-optimization and your site can be penalized. A lot of work + big disk requirement + high risk + little benefit prospect. Are you sure?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  I'm just doing what my SEO guy has requested of me.